# Laravel route() parameter UTF-8 issue

Tags: laravel, utf-8, routes, laravel-routing

I was throwing some arabic characters in the databaes until i was testing the url value of one of my tables and it was returning the encoded value of arabic letters, i checked the database it was fine, however i noticed that the issue was in the route() parameters encoding the values:

```
route('some.route', 'parmش'); // returns the encoded value 'param%D8%B4'
```

which made my db queries returns null for that row.
the database looks fine and everything else looks fine, except that i cannot find the place to fix that.

i did few more tests like

```
url('ش'); // was fine
```

**Help!**

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2396 explicitly disallows most non-ASCII characters. `route` was correct to urlencode them. `url` is wrong. If you are storing URLs you need to ensure they are valid. Sidenote: while non-ASCII characters need to be URL encoded, the browsers address bar will decode them so they would appear normal

Answer (score 4):

solved by `rawurldecode($value);`